# Reverse natural order using collections.reverseOrder()

Tags: java

I have a class that uses priority queue to display 5 strings in ascending order. I understand that to make it in descending order i can use the "collections.reverseOrder()" method. How use this method with the following code?

```
import java.util.*;
public class queue {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        PriorityQueue<String> sQ = new PriorityQueue<String>();

        sQ.add("theodore");
        sQ.add("theo");
        sQ.add("Shailee");
        sQ.add("Deborah");
        sQ.add("Fernando");
        sQ.add("th");

        while (sQ.size() > 0)
            System.out.println(sQ.remove());

        Collections.reverseOrder(); //I am stuck here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this, *before* removing the elements in `sQ`:

```
PriorityQueue<String> reversed =
    new PriorityQueue<String>(sQ.size(), new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return -o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
reversed.addAll(sQ); // now `reversed` contains the reversed priority queue
```

Because you're using the natural ordering of `String`, it makes sense to just build another `PriorityQueue` passing as a parameter a new comparator that compares strings but reversing the order (notice the `-` sign in front of the comparison).

**EDIT:**

As has been pointed in the comments, this is an even simpler solution:

```
PriorityQueue<String> reversed =
    new PriorityQueue<String>(sQ.size(), Collections.reverseOrder());
reversed.addAll(sQ);
```

Comment: Could you tell me what the "o1 an o2" is?

Comment: @Oscar You can even make it simpler than that.  This should work also:  `PriorityQueue<String> reversed = new PriorityQueue<String>( sQ.size(), Collections.reverseOrder() );`

Comment: Each pair of elements in the collection. When the queue is sorting its elements, the comparator gets called for each pair of elements to determine which one should go first

Comment: thanks for your help Oscar and Ryan... Now I created a similar while loop thats in my code above to display the elements but I keep getting an error here... "PriorityQueue<String> reversed = new PriorityQueue<String>(sQ.size(), Collections.reverseOrder());"

Comment: @theolc you're welcome!. If this answer was helpful for you, please consider accepting it as correct (click the check mark to its left)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at java.util.PriorityQueue.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at queue.main(queue.java:19)

Comment: @theolc The objects that you're adding to the `PriorityQueue`, are they `String`s ? The second solution (using `reverseOrder()` only works for simple types (strings, integers, etc.) If it's a class you made, you need to use the first solution, creating a comparator explicitly

Comment: I wish to use the same elements as listed in my original code above, therefore yes they are strings.

Comment: @theolc try with the first solution. And/or examine the stack trace to see if the error originates elsewhere; otherwise I don't know what could be wrong

Answer (score 3):

First you're removing the elements from the queue: don't forget to add them back.
And if you check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder() you'll notice how to use it :)

Best of luck!

Comment: is there a simple method to re-adding the elements?

Comment: Please reference most recent documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
    String[] strArray = new String[0];

    /*Creating array from Queue*/
    strArray = sQ.toArray(strArray);

    Arrays.sort(strArray,Collections.reverseOrder());   

    System.out.println("\n Elements of Queue in REVERSE:\n");

    for(String s:strArray)
    System.out.print(s+" ,");
```

But problem is it will also **sort** your list in reverse order